# How do calculate and convert localtime to unix time stamp in Perl

Tags: perl

My script is :

```
   use warnings;
   use strict;

my $start_time = localtime();
     $sql = "INSERT into Table1, Select (VAr1, Var2, Var3 ...........)";
my $end_time = localtime();
my $run_time = ($end_time - $start_time);

my @months = ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day,$month,$year) = (localtime($run_time))[0,1,2,3,4,5]; 
print "Unix time ".$run_time." converts to ".$months[$month]." ".$day.", ".($year +=1900);
print " ".$hour.":".$min.":".$sec."\n";
```

When I run it, I don't get the desire output.

Unix time 648 converts to Jan , 1900 ::

I need to get hour:min:sec
the time the script took to calculate the insert into the table.

Thank you

Comment: unix time has a 1970 epoch, not 1900.

Comment: Please take a little more care when writing questions on Stack Overflow. Instead of providing code that does not compile to illustrate something, you can just use comments if that part of the code is not relevant to the question. It's also nice if the output you show is actually what the program you posted is producing.

Comment: is a single insert really taking more than a fractional second?

Comment: yes, we are talking about millions of data

Answer (score 2):

`$run_time` isn't a timestamp (a number of seconds since epoch representing a date-time), so it makes no sense to pass it to `localtime`.

```
my $s = $run_time % 60;  $run_time = ($run_time - $s) / 60;
my $m = $run_time % 60;  $run_time = ($run_time - $m) / 60;
my $h = $run_time;

my $formatted_run_time = sprintf "%d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s;
```

You can get fancier too:

```
my $formatted_run_time =
   $h ? sprintf "%d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s
   $m ? sprintf "%d:%02d", $m, $s
   $s;
```

Comment: but even though it's a not timestamp, it can make sense to pass it to gmtime:  `use Time::Piece "gmtime"; say gmtime($run_time)->strftime("%H:%M:%S")`  (assumes it is less than a day)

Comment: @ysth, True, though using the builtin `gmtime` and  grabbing `strftime` from POSIX would be simpler and less magical.

Comment: I did gmtime($run_time)->strftime("%H:%M:%S") but I didn't get the run time of my script. I need h:m:s

Comment: @doudy_05, If you have a question, as a Question. I'm not playing the guessing game.

Comment: @doudy_05, Oh, I thought you wanted to use ysth's code (since you (falsly) claimed it doesn't work).

Comment: @doudy_05, huh??? Already [gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33809705/589924) you one. And so did ysth.

Comment: which one? 
use strict;
use warning;
use Benchmark;

my $t0 = Benchmark->new;

# do your database stuff here

my $t1 = Benchmark->new;
my $td = timediff($t1, $t0);
print "the code took:",timestr($td),"\n";

Comment: @doudy_05, Which one what? Why one is my answer? The one with my name on it. I even linked to it in the comment!

Comment: I have a script to insert new data into a table anytime  I run it. so, I want to calculate the execution time for the entire process. 
Im using :
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::localtime;
use Benchmark;
the output Im getting is: Execution time: 0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.00 CPU)

Comment: That code does NOT produce that output, and that has nothing to do with my answer. If you have a new question, post a Question, not a comment.

Comment: @doudy if you want the run time of the entire process, just use the `time` program from the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I'll try it , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`localtime` is used to convert unix timestamps to a human-readable time (or a list of parts of it), but you are giving it a *duration* in seconds. It will treat it like a timestamp, and give you a very low date and time.

```
print scalar localtime 648;
# gives Thu Jan  1 01:10:48 1970
```

Your code gives the following output:

> Unix time 648 converts to Jan 1, 1970 1:10:48

The problem is that you are essentially mixing two concepts here.

**You might want to use the [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module instead**, which is intended for this exact purpose.

```
use strict;
use warning;
use Benchmark;

my $t0 = Benchmark->new;

# do your database stuff here

my $t1 = Benchmark->new;
my $td = timediff($t1, $t0);
print "the code took:",timestr($td),"\n";
```

---

If you are on a Linux or Unix, you can also use [the `time` program](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to meassure the overall runtime of your program.

```
$ time perl foo.pl
real    0m2.241s
user    0m2.236s
sys 0m0.000s

$
```

Comment: / It didn't work :
Execution time: 0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.00 CPU)

Comment: @doudy_05 if all you are doing is setting a `$sql` variable, not actually running a query, that would make sense

Comment: my script is to run a query to insert new values into a table and the duration is 1m07s

Comment: This is the Output I got : 
the code took: 0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.00 CPU)

Comment: @doudy you might have put the first Benchmark object below the code you want to time.